# Is "send us a page with code" a typical interview requirement?

Tags: interview, source-code

Recently I was asked to show "a page with code" for a job interview. Being mainly a back-end programmer, and that's the position I applied for, I first said to the person I was talking to exactly that: PHP is executed at the server and therefore not visible by just giving a "page".

However, following their desire, I sent links to the pages I've worked on before. Obviously they couldn't see anything except for the HTML, CSS, JS... They said it was not enough, they could not see the PHP.

Understanding that they probably just wanted to know my skills and/or interest I sent them my Stack Overflow profile. Among all my questions and answers, most of them with code, certainly the PHP is there. But it seems this is not what they wanted.

Well, I don't have any code put together that I can simply publish for someone to see. And I would never do it for the code I have deployed, obviously.

So my question is/are: What does "send us a page with code" mean? What should I send? Is this a typical interview requirement?

Comment: From the recruiting person's point of view, this just says to them that you lack commitment to come up with a decent sample of code. I recommend you make an effort, write up some code to do something, anything really and send it to them

Comment: They probably want to see _how_ you code. Send them a tiny sample project. Or point them to a online repository of yours if you have.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It means send some source code. It is a quite common interview candidacy request.

You should do it. It doesn't have to make much sense to them. They just want to see some basic flow and good coding style.

A long time ago during my job searching, I solved a bunch of old ACM programming contest questions in a variety of languages. I use those for code samples.

Regardless how this job prospect turns out for you, I'd recommend putting together some samples for your next prospect. When we've considered people in the past, I always ask to see some code. I don't even bother compiling or executing it or anything, I am more interested to see structure, commenting, and that it doesn't look like [this sort of stuff](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/No-Letters-Allowed!.aspx).

Comment: I have a lot of code I used to solve Project Euler questions however I don't consider that a bunch of loops would fit in as a good coding and expertise example.

Comment: @andre matos: so split it into functions, pretty it up a little, and use that. Writing a program to solve a very difficult mathematical challenge can be a great code sample.

Comment: I was wondering... If the goal is to avoid something like what you show at dailywtf link, shouldn't the javascript be enough? Everyone coding style is surely similar between PHP and JS...

Comment: For those that ask for this - how can you be sure that what the candidate is sending you was actually written by him/her? Do you ask them to explain it to you or read it for you? We always ask candidates to write a small snippet during the interview and do a mock code review on a piece of code we give them.

Comment: @Dave, these are usually "rejection" steps. If someone can't give you a decent snippet of code even with help (Google/Friends), he is either not interested in position or not capable.   If you have 100s of resumes, steps like these reduce that number a lot.

Comment: After reading the "sort of stuff" and **the comment to that** I was frankly terrified about how many of them focused on the poor structure, without even get what the *real* problem was. (the *logic inversion*: to permit only numbers he denied all the ASCII non-number individually. Every other non-number that lives outside the 0..127 space remained permitted!)  If that's the result, I wonder about the knowledge of recruiters!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Using weird characters was addressed right in the intro to the code sample. "Tháñk göödñéss ñóbódÿ üsés wíërd sɹǝʇʇǝן!" Either way it doesn't take much thinking to realize that code sample is swill, and any applicant submitting that would be rightly rejected.

Answer (score 4):

While their request isn't *abnormal*, it is much more productive to have a candidate actually *write* some code during an interview that solves a problem that the interviewer described. Or, perhaps you'll be asked to review a random snippet of code from their production stuff and provide feedback. Hopefully, you'll be asked both.

You really want to work at a company that asks you this, because it means the people who will be working with you in the future have to pass through the same filter.

Still, why not publish a few useful bits of boilerplate stuff that all of us have laying around on a site like Github? Keep it up to date, refine it (in other words, don't just drop it and forget about it) and send *that* stuff with your application. Also indicate something like:

```
I love solving problems on the spot! Please give me something to solve
during the interview.
```

That's not at all inappropriate, and might help you get around a (lack of) available snippets to send.

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure what they want... maybe a sample program? For web demos you might have to bundle with a server configuration? I'm not sure how I'd do that if I were asked. Even the phrase "a page with code" is not easy to understand... do they want an actual printed letter-format page of PHP? Do they want an executable demo "page" from a website (forget the fact it might not work without the context of the rest of the site). Are they able to further clarify this requirement?

But if they are hiring for a PHP developer and they can't understand that the PHP from a live site will never be visible to them, maybe this is a sign to look for a knowledgable potential employee?

Comment: That's what I thought first. But there's an intermediary between the employee and me so I'm not sure who's the fault. :-)

Comment: @andre matos: Oh. If this is a non-technical recruiter who has no idea what's what you really might need to press them for clarification by presenting them with different possible options for WTF "page with code" means... Or try to contact the employee/hiring manager directly if possible.

Comment: Believe me, I did. By now, I believe the recruiter might think I'm a moron by the way I said that showing PHP code is a WTF. :-)

Comment: @andre matos: It's not a complete WTF, but they way the asked for it was. You could offer to show them a sample program, something simple that takes a user's form input then prints the string in reverse or something, just to *prove* that you actually know PHP. But I'm not a fan of such questions because they're easy to fake the answers to if you have the right friends. The real test comes in a face-to-face where you can actually  *talk* about coding!

Comment: I don't know, it seemed pretty clear to me that they were asking for a page of PHP, where "page" means a printed page worth (50-60 lines) of code.  I try not to assume my potential employers are morons, it makes interviews depressing.

Answer (score 1):

I have been asked before to send/email code samples, once I demoed a web site to them.  There's nothing wrong with that.  You send what they require.  If you going for an ASP.NET job, then it'll be code-behind and the aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are stuck with some process. Talking directly to hiring manager might do the trick.

Or you can write a "page" with generic problems like some aspects of shopping cart and show that you care about code quality aspects like unit tests / comments / error handling etc.

Answer (score 1):

While applying for my current job they asked for a couple examples of my PHP programming.

I searched through all the code I had written and found examples of my better work.

I believe you are concerned about the 'rights' to showing a new possible employer code that you done for someone else in the past.

I would not be too concerned over this **as long as you don't give any code that could be considered a trade secret**.

Take a class that you wrote and remove any specifics about who it was written for and any trade secret sections.

Your prospective employer is (hopefully) not looking to steal code from your previous employers, they just want to ensure that you know something of proper coding technique/organization.

So by providing sections of code that, for all intents and purposes, is useless outside the project for which it was written, you satisfy your prospective employers need to see your output while still maintaining your ethics and not sharing trade secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Asking to send code -- I dunno.
Using previously written code in interview is IMO fair game. On interview I always have a pen drive in my pocket with my previous work, and happy to show it if there is an interest. (And there is no interest O,O.  Droid interviewer sticks to make me reimplement strstr() or strcat() rather than accepting to look my solution for real world problems...)

As interviewer I'd be more than happy with such offer. I would not ask to send code as it is useless without context and explanation. code review works best if done face to face. ;-)